# Getting error when creating trigger

Tags: sql-server-2014

I get an error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure CUSTOMER_DELETE, Line 37
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

when trying to create this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[CUSTOMER_DELETE]  
   ON  [DBO].[CUSTOMER] 
   AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

       DECLARE @CustNo INT

       SELECT @CustNo = DELETED.CustNo     
       FROM DELETED

       INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
       VALUES(@CustNo, 'Deleted')
END
```

Comment: Trying to find out how to execute this trigger correctly...Please help!

Comment: The immediate error is the fact that your table `Customer` obviously has a lot more columns than just the two you provide values for. You should **always** explicitly define the columns you want to insert into: `INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(CustomerNo, Status) VALUES (@CustNo, 'Deleted');`......

Answer (score 0):

The immediate error is the fact that your table `Customer` obviously has a lot more columns than just the two you provide values for. You should **always** explicitly define the columns you want to insert into: `INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(CustomerNo, Status) VALUES (@CustNo, 'Deleted');`...

But then again: when you *delete* one customer - do you really want to insert a **new row** into the customer table?? I suspect you're more likely wanting to **update** the existing (deleted) row with new values - use an `UPDATE` statement for that.

But the much **deeper** problem is that your trigger has **MAJOR** design flaw: you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `DELETE` statement that causes this trigger to fire delete 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Deleted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select? It's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

So putting it all together, I **assume** what you *really* want is something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[CUSTOMER_DELETE]  
ON [dbo].[CUSTOMER] 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- ONE, single nice set-based UPDATE statement to update 
    -- the "Status" column for those rows that were deleted by
    -- your DELETE statement
    UPDATE dbo.Customer
    SET Status = 'Deleted'   -- adapt to what your column is really called here!    
    FROM Deleted d
    WHERE dbo.Customer.CustomerNo = d.CustomerNo
END
```